# Is it possible to group by field name using django orm?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have two models:

```py
class ExampleOne(models.Model):
    # some fields
    
class ExampleTwo(models.Model):
    example_one = models.ForeignKey(
        "App.ExampleOne",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="examples",
    )
    field_one = ...
    field_two = ...
```

And I created this view for my endpoint:

```py
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = ExampleOne.objects.all().values(
            "id",
            "examples__field_one",
            "examples__field_two",
        )
        return Response({"data": queryset})
```

That return this:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "examples__id": 1,
      "examples__field_one": foo,
      "examples__field_two": bar,
    },
    {
    {
      "id": 1,
      "examples__id": 2,
      "examples__field_one": foo,
      "examples__field_two": bar,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "examples__id": 3,
      "examples__field_one": foo,
      "examples__field_two": bar,
    }
```

But I wanted a way to group by the first model. It's possible? I wanted something like this:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "1": [
            {
            "examples__id": 1,
            "examples__field_one": foo,
            "examples__field_two": bar,
            },
            {
            "examples__id": 2,
            "examples__field_one": foo,
            "examples__field_two": bar,
            },      
      ],
      "2": [
            {
            "examples__id": 3,
            "examples__field_one": foo,
            "examples__field_two": bar,
            },      
      ]
    }
}
```

It's possible? All information I find about grouping involves values (count, sum, ...). But I just wanted to group by one field (model one id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no straightforward way of doing this with the Django ORM.

## Using raw SQL

One option is to use a raw SQL query, but offtopic as you specified you wanted to achieve this using the ORM.

## Modifying the `query.group_by` attribute

Another is to modify the `group_by` attribute of the `query` of a given queryset (that will roughly translate in a `GROUP_BY` SQL statement):

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
qs.query.group_by = ['my_field']
```

This is **not** recommanded as it's not a documented API, and it might (will?) do unwanted stuff on your queryset.

## Building the dict yourself

One other option is to not use the ORM directly:

```
group_by_values = MyModel.objects.values_list(
    'group_by_field', flat=True
).distinct() # This is a list of all existing values for group_by_field

result = {
    value: MyModel.objects.filter(group_by_field=value)
    for value in group_by_values
}
```

## Third-party option

One last option is to use a third party lib, like [django-group-by](https://pypi.org/project/django-group-by/).

## When dealing with template display only (unrelevant to you)

The `{% regroup %}` template tag is perfect for this. See [its docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup).

Comment: hey Le Minaw, thank you. Distinct works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
class ExampleOne(models.Model):
    # some fields
    
class ExampleTwo(models.Model):
    example_one = models.ForeignKey(
        "App.ExampleOne",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="examples",
    )
    field_one = ManyToManyField(YourModel, related_name="*")
    field_two = ManyToManyField(YourModel, related_name="*")
```

or you can using forloop

```
data = []
for i in yourmodel:
    dicts = {}
    dicts["id"] = i.id
    dicts["your_data"] = [{i.model_1}]
    data.append(dicts)
return Response({"data": data})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
queryset_data={}
for e in queryset:
  if e.value('id') not in new_data :
    new_data[e.value('id')]=[e.value("examples__id","examples__field_one","examples__field_two")]
  else :
    new_data[e.value('id')].append(e.value("examples__id","examples__field_one","examples__field_two"))
return Response({"data": queryset_data})
```